# Netbeans Plugin development: @ActionReference paths reference

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins

I am developing a Netbeans plugin which will verify a Web Project against some rules.
I am trying to add it a menu as a first item in the Projects context menu.  From what I understand, this is done by specifing the path attribute in the @ActionReference annotation.  Anyone knows where to find a complete reference for the possible paths?

This is what I have now, and my Menu item appears somewhere in the bottom of the Projects context menu, so I suspect I need something different than "Projects/Actions"

```
@ActionID(
    category = "Tools",
id = "org.chain.war.WarVerifier")
@ActionRegistration(
    displayName = "#CTL_WarVerifier")
@ActionReference(path = "Projects/Actions", position = 0)
public final class WarVerifier implements ActionListener
```

I am on Netbeans 7.2

Thanks, 
Chris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on one your package **New** > **Other...**  and under **Module Development** choose **XML Layer**.

This XML Layer will show as a drop down containing 2 elements, choose **this layer in context** you will have the full hierarchy.